# Как правильно записать название учебного заведения?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно записать: ученик МОУ Октябрьской СОШ или ученик МОУ Октябрьская СОШ?

Хотелось бы видеть документ, на основании которого можно обосновать верную запись фразы.

Answer (score 1):

"Октябрьская СОШ" - имя собственное муниципального общеобразовательного учреждения:

*Ученик МОУ "Октябрьская СОШ".*

Склонять не надо. Точного правила не найду, но не совпадает род (учреждение - школа).

Может быть, этот источник подойдёт - как ориентир:

**[Муниципальные общеобразовательные учреждения](http://www.raionistra.ru/admin/uprav/obr/doc/info1.html)**

---

По следам комментариев:

Сообразила, что дело не в роде, а в том, что закавыченное название сохраняет свой именительный падеж.

*Магазин "Снежная королева" - ученик продавца магазина "Снежная королева".*

Падеж названия может быть и не именительным - *кафе "В пути...",* - важно, что оно (закавыченное название) остаётся неизменным.

Comment: Интересно, почему в этом источнике нет кавычек в *МОУ Лицей г. Истры*?

Comment: Ну откуда ж мне знать, отчего где-то чего-то нетути? Чего ни хватись, как говорится, ничего у вас нет... Но ответ я дополню другими соображениями.

Comment: это не претензия, вы не подумайте)) чистый интерес

Comment: Кстати, слово "лицей", скорее всего, употреблено в его прямом смысле, не как ансамбль песни и пляски "Купалинка", но при этом лицей является муниципальным общеобразовательным учреждением.

Comment: Извините, что вмешиваюсь, но недавно сталкивалась с чем-то подобным. Я думаю, нет кавычек, потому что их нет в Уставе и других учредительных документах образовательного учреждения. А наименование (название) учебного заведения (теперь учебной организации) во всех документах должно точно соответствовать наименованию в Уставе. Следовательно, если какой -то "грамотей" не поставил их в учредительных документах, то все вопросы к нему...

Answer (score 0):

Как правильно записать: ученик МОУ Октябрьской СОШ или ученик МОУ Октябрьская СОШ?
Согласна с Галиной. Правильно записывают, расшифровывая и склоняя аббревиатуры, указывающие на тип и вид образовательного или иного учреждения. Само название учреждения в кавычках (или без них) при этом не склоняется, если рядом стоит эта аббревиатура. Если её нет, то название склоняется.

Например, я учусь в муниципальном образовательном учреждении Октябрьская средняя общеобразовательная школа или я учусь в муниципальном образовательном учреждении "Октябрьская средняя общеобразовательная школа"

Понятно, что трудно представить склонение аббревиатуры как сложносокращённого слова. Поэтому мы "представляем", что просклоняли его и просто записываем:  ученик МОУ Октябрьская СОШ.
Если бы не было указания на тип и вид учреждения, мы бы склоняли само название. Ученик Октябрьской СОШ.

Ещё посмотрите, пожалуйста,  на [gramota.ru](http://gramota.ru)

Answer (score 0):

Лучше узнать в конкретной школе, ибо в моей было правильно 'МОУ со школа №' .